# How to estimate the weights for a weighted average if not every weight is used in every example?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Say that you have a data set that contains $N$ examples. For each example, there are three main sections of important information. The first most important piece of information is the name of the example, called $i$. The second most important piece of information is the weighted average, or score. The score is a real number $x$ in the interval $[0, 100]$. The third most important section of information is the set of all the weights and their associated scores. For each weight, there is a unique name associated with it, called $j$.

The goal I have is to estimate the weights that are used in computing the scores in the examples. But there is a catch. Not every name and its associated weight is used in every single example.

Each example $i$ is associated with a subset $S_i$ of $[1...j]$. I suspect the weighted average (or score) for $i$ is

$y_i =$ $(\sum_{j \in S_i} W_j*X_{i,j})/(\sum_{j \in S_i} W_j)$

For instance: suppose you have one example called "Blue," and it has a score of 90, that has the following names and their associated ratings,

Roxanne 50

Alice 70

But in another example called "Red," there is a score of 75 with the following info:

Roxanne 80

Bob 10

So given this, how do I find how Alice is weighted as well as Bob? More generally, how do I find the value for each weight for every name across all $N$
examples? Across all of the examples, the number of rows will not be constant. Some examples will have five ratings, but others will have just three. Assume that $N$ is not small, such that $N > 100$.